# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

Tags: python, pandas

merged_df:

```
index   (app_date, )    (Nifty50_returns, ) (ABC_returns, ) segment     case_count
0   0   2017-04-03     0.001869               0.006906          1        5.0
1   1   2017-04-03     0.001869               0.006906          1        13.0
2   2   2017-04-03     0.001869               0.006906          1        1.0
3   3   2017-04-03     0.001869               0.006906          1        9.0
4   4   2017-04-03     0.001869               0.006906          1         0.0
```

Now I am trying to rename columns so that the bracket and comma is removed from columns:

```
mapping = {merged_df.columns[0]:'Index', merged_df.columns[1]: 'application_date', merged_df.column[2]:'Nifty50returns'}

merged_df.rename(columns=mapping)
```

But I get error:

```
 AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'
```

If it helps below are some facts

```
[IN]merged_df.columns
[OUT]:
Index([                 'index', ('app_date', ''),
        ('Nifty50_returns', ''),      ('ABC_returns', ''),
                         'case_count'],
      dtype='object')
```

How to rename?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake here: `merged_df.column[2]`. It is `columns` not `column`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is just because you wrote `column` instead of `columns` in the third rename:

`mapping = {merged_df.columns[0]:'Index', merged_df.columns[1]: 'application_date', merged_df.column[2]:'Nifty50returns'}`